# Display nodes in swagger whose values are returning null

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-web-api2

I have following JSON format and data, and in few nodes I am getting null values. Check below JSON data. In Swagger that nodes are not displaying whose values are null in get request.

For example below, IsTest1 and IsTest2 are not displaying in Get request in swagger response. But I like to display it in JSON response, so any one know how can I do that.

```
{
    "IsTest1": null,
    "IsTest2": null,
    "Client3": "client-data",
    "Status": 3
}
```

In swagger it is returning only below data but I want all nodes also whose values are null.

```
{
  "data": {
    "client3" : "client-data"
      }
    "status": 3
  },
  "statusCode": 200,
  "successMessage": "Successful"
}
```

I am using .Net-Core

Comment: In my case,it would display the  properties  which are null ,how  did you configured?

Comment: Can you share the code about how you return this data?

Comment: just add `[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include)]` to the properties `IsTest1` and `IsTest2` and try